# i want responsive page when i compress my window

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

In this executed normally in the maximized window but i think its not responsive because when i compress the window the design view as vertically one by one but i want horizontal view

```
<div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                      <span class="text-center"><b>SELLERS</b></span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1">
                       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down">RATING</span>
                 </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up">DELIVERED BY</span>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-md-1">
                       <span class="text-center">OFFERS</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down">PRICE</span>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-md-2">
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is correct. Currently your columns will stack when they hit the 'medium' breakpoint, which is 992 pixels according to the [Grid table on the Bootstrap website](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options). This means once your browser width slips below 992 pixels width it will revert to stacked.

You can change your `col-md-*` classes to be `col-sm-*`, this will make them change to stacked at the 'small' breakpoint, which is 768 pixels. For more information carefully read the documentation and examples here - http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid